# Running an if statement and storing the results in a vector

Tags: if-statement

I want to run an if statement with three potential outcomes:

```
   'FTH>FTA = "Home"
   FTH<FTA = "Away"
   FTH=FTA = "Draw"'
```

FTH & FTA are two integer variables

I want to store the answer in a vector.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved

Win <- ifelse(r1<0,"A", ifelse (r1>0,"H", "D")) # Full-time